# Invalid element name:- display-name One of the following is expected:- distributable, context-param , filter, servlet, etc

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, element

I am trying to solve this error...
This error is showing by default when I create new project within dynamic web project option..
The scenario is project creates successfully but when I expand web.xml file inside webapp folder errors are showing....

Pls click the code of web.xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" 
encodingg="UTF-8"?>
<web-appxmlns:xsi="http://
www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance" 
xmlnss="http://java.sun.com
/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsii:schemaLocation="http:
//java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
httpp://java.sun.com/xml/
ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
versionn="2.5">
<display-name>helloweb</display- 
name>
</web-app>
```

This is the error:-
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/savdu.png]

Comment: It should be like...


<?xml version="1.0" encodingg="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlnss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
          xsii:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        versionn="2.5">
<display-name>helloweb</display-name>
</web-app>

Comment: correcting a typo..
<?xml version="1.0" encodingg="UTF-8"?> <web-app xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlnss="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" versionn="2.5"> <display-name>helloweb</display-name> </web-app>

Answer (score 0):

Just change `xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"` to `xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"`